# Java program with different classes with same method name in case of inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance

```
class GrandFather
{
    void display1()
    {
        System.out.println("I am grandfather");
    }
}

class Father extends GrandFather
{
    void display()
    {
        System.out.println("I am father");
    }
}

class Children extends Father
{
    void display()
    {
       System.out.println("I am Child");
    }

    public static void main(String []args)
    {
       Children obj = new Children();

       obj.display();
       obj.display();
       obj.display();
    }
}
```

When I am compiling this code it is printing the display method of last class so tell me how to cast it to print the display of parent and other class

Comment: To invoke the parent class you could use super

Comment: How in the world would the JVM know which method to choose on each call? You only have Children objects so only the Children method is invoked. If you like the Father method or the GrandFather method to be invoked, you'll need an instance of them.

Comment: @daniel can you explain more in detail how to invoke method

Answer (score 0):

```
GrandFather obj = new GrandFather();
```

//prints the grandfather's display method.

```
obj = new Father();
```

//prints the Father's display method.

```
obj = new Children();
```

//prints the Childrens's display method.
If you want everything to be called make use of super in display() method.

Comment: else you can use super keyword.

Comment: You don't have to worry about upcasing but you should taken care for downcasing(e.g. Children ob = (GrandFather) new GrandFather(); )

Comment: @Shriram We can't use super in static context.

Comment: where is the static in the above program?

Comment: @Shriram main() is static! Please tell me if I missed anything. :)

Comment: @Shivam A cast doesn't change an objects class. You can in fact cast an object to any of its parent classes (`Children c = new Children(); Father f = (Father) c;`) but a call to `f.display()` will still print `I am Child` because the class of `c` is still `Children` and that is what an instance of `Children` displays. This has to do with the way Java uses [late binding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Late_binding#Late_binding_in_Java). Simply speaking: A call to a method is picked up by the most recent implementation (inheritance-wise) of that method.

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the name of display function in Father class to display2 then the following will work:

```
class GrandFather {
    void display1() {
        System.out.println("I am grandfather");
    }
}

class Father extends GrandFather {
    void display2() {
        System.out.println("I am father");
    }
}

class Children extends Father {
    void display() {
        System.out.println("I am Child");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Children obj = new Children();

        obj.display1();
        obj.display2();
        obj.display();
    }
}
```

What you are trying to achieve otherwise violates the spirit of OOPS concepts.

Comment: I does want to change the method name I want to display results using same method name

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply the parents behaviour on every child object, you can do like:

```
class GrandFather {
    void display() {
        System.out.println("I am grandfather");
    }
}

class Father extends GrandFather {
    void display() {
        super.display();
        System.out.println("I am father");
    }
}

class Children extends Father {
    void display() {
        super.display();
        System.out.println("I am Child");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Children obj = new Children();

        obj.display();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call super.display() in every display method apart from GrandFather class this will print all the values. I.e Grandfather -> Father -> Child.

Answer (score 0):

It's the **OOP concept** (polymorphisme). To use a parent method **implementation** you can use a **superclass instance** for the children reference. For example :

Display "I'm children" :

```
Children children = new Children ();
children.display();
```

Display "I'm father" :

```
Children children = new Father ();
children.display();
```

Display "I'm grand father" :

```
Children children = new GrandFather ();
children.display();
```

Or you can use the `super` keyword in your method :

```
class Children extends Father {
  public void display () {
     super.display();
  }
}

Children children = new Children ();
//Display "I'm a father"
children.display();
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing you need to learn is proper indentation of code.  Your original code is too messy to read.

Second, we come to the question you are asking:  What you are asking for is against the principle of polymorphism (at least in Java).

When you have a `Children` object instance, although it can be viewed as a `Father` or a `GrandFather`, in real it is still a `Children` and it act as `Children` even you treat it as a `Father`.  It is one of the most important and core principle in OOP.

So you cannot take a `Children` instance and make it works as a `Father` (i.e. when calling `display()`, shows `father` instead of `children`).

There are some ways to workaround it, one way is, as other answer has already mentioned, do not override the method to be called.  Split them into separate methods, e.g.

```
// in pseudo code
class GrandFather {
    public void displayAsGrandFather() { 
        print("I am grandfather"); 
    }
    public void display() { 
        displayAsGrandFather(); 
    }
}

class Father {
    public void displayAsFather() { 
        print("I am father"); 
    }
    public void display() { 
        displayAsFather(); 
    }
}
class Child {
    public void displayAsChild(){ 
        print("I am child"); 
    }
    public void display() { 
        displayAsChild();
    }
}
```

then you can do something like:

```
Child child = new Child();
child.displayAsGrandFather();
child.displayAsFather();
child.displayAsChild();
```

---

Or actually invoke `display()` on different type of object instance:

```
new Child().display();
new Father().display();
new GrandFather().display();
```

---

Another less obvious way to avoid overriding is to make `display()` a static method, given that you are not using any instance members.  Static method resolution is performed in compile time, instead of runtime (as in normal overridden instance methods).

For example:

```
// in pseudo code
class GrandFather {
    public static void display() { 
        print("I am grandfather"); 
    }
}

class Father {
    public static void display() { 
        print("I am father"); 
    }
}
class Child {
    public static void display() { 
        print("I am child"); 
    }
}
```

hence, you can do

```
Child child = new Child();
child.display();    // will be translated to Child.display() by compiler
((Father)child).display();  // will be translated to Father.display() by compiler
((GrandFather)child).display();  // will be translated to GrandFather.display() by compiler
```

---

IMHO, although the problem is not unsolvable, it is actually quite meaningless to discuss on it, as it is against the principle of OOP, and there is no meaningful real-life scenario for this.